# Need to return a tuple from a dictionary with the highest value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

This is the code I have so far:

```
def most_oscars(d):
    v=list(d.values())
    k=list(d.keys())
    return k[v.index(max(v))]
```

Current output:

```
Meryl Streep
```

But it needs to print like `('Meryl Streep', 20)`

What do I need to add/change?

Comment: `return k[v.index(max(v))], max(v)`

Comment: `max(d.items(),key=lambda x: x[1])` will do the job!

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter).

```
import operator

def most_oscars(d):
    return max(d.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))

nominees = {'Meryl Streep': 20, 'Robert De Niro': 7, 'Michael Caine': 6, 'Maggie Smith': 6}

print(most_oscars(nominees))

# ('Meryl Streep', 20)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's entirely feasible for two actors to have the same maximum number of Oscars, you can use a list comprehension to return a list of tuples:

```
def most_oscars(d):
    maxval = max(d.values())
    return [(k, v) for k, v in d.items() if v == maxval]

nominees = {'Meryl Streep': 20, 'Robert De Niro': 20, 'Michael Caine': 6, 'Maggie Smith': 6}

print(most_oscars(nominees))

# [('Meryl Streep', 20), ('Robert De Niro', 20)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def most_oscars(d):
    max_key = max(d, key=d.get)
    reslt_pair = tuple([max_key,d[max_key]])
    print(reslt_pair)
```